# Where to ask help about support horror stories?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions

I am having a support horror story with Google, that doesn't want to replace my Nexus 5 that went in bootloop while in warranty (and is currently dead).

Is there is a place on Stack Exchange to talk about those kind of issues? I have looked all around, but I am not sure if some site would be good for this.

I imagine one can ask on Super User how to bring the phone back to life, if possible, but I would like to resolve the issue with the horror story first.

Comment: I feel that they aren't properly handling my case. They didn't provide a solution to make my phone work again, and they don't want to replace it. Since I request their help with that issue while I was in warranty terms, I feel they are violating the law.

Comment: If that's the case, then you probably need to contact a lawyer. Or, more practically, take them to small claims court.

Comment: I wasn't aware Google sells smartphones directly, I think in my country we have only local vendors, which are "easier" to sue in such cases. Good luck, I fear you're going to need it! ):

Comment: Join me in calling them G$$GLE.  Join *us*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have specific questions to ask, then [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) would be the place. (Smartphones are explicitly off-topic at [Super User](http://superuser.com).)

In fact, there's over [400 questions with the `boot-loop` tag there](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-loop).

If you want to "talk" about the issue, or helping you will require a lot of back-and-forth, then Stack Exchange isn't the right place for that. However, you might be able to get some help at the [Android Enthusiasts chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts).

Answer (score 3):

About the legal perspective you can also get answers on http://law.stackexchange.com .